# deseo cambiar el estado de todos los registros segun la fecha actual automaticamente

Tags: php

deseo cambiar el estado de todos los registros segun la fecha actual automaticamente,pero el siguiente codigo actualiza todos los datos segun el primer registro

```
include('php/connection.php');
$hoy = date('Y-m-d');   
$sql = "select * from agenda";  
$edit = mysql_query($sql,$cn);  
$row = mysql_fetch_array($edit);
$fecDB = $row['fecha_fin'];

if($fecDB<$hoy)
{
    $estado = "VENCIDO";
}
elseif ($fecDB>=$hoy) 
{
    $estado = "EN PROCESO"; 
}    

$sql = "update agenda set estado='$estado' where (fecha_fin<'$hoy')     OR  ".
"(fecha_fin>='$hoy')";
```

Comment: Tu campo fecha_fin debe ser tipo date.

Comment: ¿No te falta aquí el signo de igualdad `=`: `fecha_fin<'$hoy'`...    Y revisa que el campo de la BD tenga el mismo formato que `$hoy`. Por otra parte, estás usando una [extensión obsoleta](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-query.php): `mysql_`... tus datos pueden correr peligro de [Inyección SQL](http://php.net/manual/es/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Comment: si todo eso revise el problema es que al momento que actualiza verifica el primer registro y si cumple la condicion con el primer registro cambia el estado a todos los registro, asi los demas registros no cumplan la condicion

Comment: $fecDB = $row['fecha_fin'] es la misma fecha para todos los registros ¿? Por que te esta tomando el valor estado y como todos los registros son menor que tu fecha actual o son mayores o igual a tu fecha actual, te va a actualizar todos con el valor que este tomando $estado

Answer (score 2):

Intenta esto:

```
include('php/connection.php');
$hoy = date('Y-m-d');   
$sql = "UPDATE agenda SET estado = IF(fecha_fin<'$hoy','VENCIDO','EN PROCESO');";
```

> Probado y funcionando.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: si salio gracias Jorny

Comment: de nada brother

Comment: hola Jorny una consulta respecto al codigo mostrado de que manera podria hacer que cuando un estado este como atendido, ya no cumpla el cambio de estado

Comment: Prueba esto y suerte: $sql = "UPDATE agenda SET estado = IF(fecha_fin<'$hoy','VENCIDO','EN PROCESO') WHERE estado<>'ATENDIDO';";